# How to disable browser Save As( File-> Save As ) by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking some information on about-

How to disable all browsers "Save as"(File -> Save As) function.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you open in a modal window and disable right click on the mouse?

Comment: But even with Valamas suggestion: You should not. It's not good practice.

Comment: i agree. but sometimes there is a specific use. Like a school exam test.

Comment: But why would you want to do that?

Comment: If security is important, forget it. I would just overwrite your JavaScript with Firebug. :-P

Answer (score 5):

You cannot disable this feature on all browsers.  If you don't want someone saving your content then you should watermark the content with your logo/copyright.  Otherwise, you may want to install some kind of access control around whatever it is your trying to avoid people from accessing and therefore having the ability to save.

Comment: +1 for the watermark idea. I remember it used to be popular years ago though it has fallen out of fashion lately.